# Can I have a Typescript function that returns a scalar or array value without the caller needing to cast the output

Tags: typescript

### Problem

I have this function:

```
save<T>(x: T | T[]) {
 if (x instanceof Array) {
     // save array to db
 } else {
     // save entity to db
 }
 return x
}

// client code
let o: SomeType = { // values here }
let updated = save(o) // compile confusion...
```

TS doesn't know if `updated` is singular or an array.

### Question

How can I define the function so that:

- if a singular parameter is passed, typescript knows that the result is singular
- if an array parameter is passed, typescript knows that the result is an array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `T[]` from the definition. `T[]` is a subset of `T`.

```
function save<T>(x: T): T {
    if (x instanceof Array) {
        // save array to db
    } else {
        // save entity to db
    }

    return x
}

// client code
let a: SomeType = { // values here };
let updateda = save(a); // updateda is of type SomeType

let b: SomeType = { // values here };
let updatedb = save([a, b]); // updatedb is of type SomeType[]
```